# Mathematica is not solving a nonlinear equations system with variables powered to rational exponents

Tags: equation-solving, nonlinear

I am trying to solve a system of 3 equations with 3 variables in Mathematica. The issue is that in this equations I have several parameters, and this makes the involved variables to be powered at fractional exponents and that seems to be making difficult the solution of the system.

I´ve first created some functions for using them within the equations of the system:

```
F[x_] = x/(Eb);
G[x_] = ((1 - a - b)/((2 - a - b) (Eb)))*((Eb^((2 - a - b)/(1 - a - b))) - (x^((2 - a - b)/(1 - a - b))));
Ea[w_, Y_] = p^(-1)*w*Y^(-m)*(-Kb)^(-a)*b^(-1)*(-Lb)^(1 - b);
```

Then, the equations of the system are:

```
eqn1 = Y == (r/a)^(a/(m (a + b) + a + b - 1)) (w/b)^(b/(m (a + b) + a + b - 1)) (p)^(-1/(m (a + b) + a + b - 1)) (G[Ea[w, Y]])^((1 - a - b)/(-m (a + b) - a - b + 1));
eqn2 = L0 == Lb (1 - F[Ea[w, Y]]) + Y^(m/(1 - a - b)) (r/a)^(a/(a + b - 1)) (w/
        b)^((1 - a)/(a + b - 1)) (p)^(-1/(a + b - 1)) (G[Ea[w, Y]]);
eqn3 = K0 == Kb (1 - F[Ea[w, Y]]) + Y^(m/(1 - a - b)) (r/a)^((a + b - a*b)/((a + b - 1) (a - 1))) (w/b)^(b/(a + b - 1)) (p)^(-1/(a + b - 1)) (G[Ea[w, Y]]);
```

The program could not give me any analytical solution by running Solve nor Reduce:

```
Solve[{eqn1, eqn2, eqn3}, {r, w, Y}]
Reduce[{eqn1, eqn2, eqn3}, {r, w, Y}]
```

After that, I decided to look for a solution with specific values for the parameters in the system, so I gave values to them, but when using Solve I got the empty set as solution, and when using Reduce I got the message

```
"Reduce::naqs: eqn1&&eqn2&&eqn3 is not a quantified system of equations and inequalities".
```

```
a = 3/10
b = 2/5
p = 1/5
m = 2
Kb = -20
Lb = -30
Eb = 5
L0 = 150
K0 = 150
```

Finally, I tried to find a numerical solution with NSolve but the code just never stopped to work on it.

I have been reading many things trying to make it work but have not been able to realize the reason why this happens.

Could you please help me to realize what the problem is?! Thankss, in advance.